# GitHubのプルリクエストでレビューを受けた後の適切なコミット反映方法は？

Tags: git, github

GitHubで、あるOSSに対してプルリクエストを行った結果、レビュー指摘を受けた場合の適切な指摘反映方法を教えていただきたいです。ただし、最終的にプルリクエストは1コミットにまとめないといけないとします（おそらく、どのOSSでもそうだと思いますが）。

私の方法では指摘をローカルのソースコードに反映して、以下を実施しています。

```
$ git commit -am "レビュー指摘の反映"
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
・・・squashで2つのコミットをまとめる（上記コミットメッセージは削除）・・・
$ git push -f origin [プルリクのためにつくったブランチ]
```

この場合、プルリクエストは1コミットにまとめられますが、レビュー指摘前のソースコードが完全になくなってしまうので、レビュアーは適切にレビュー指摘を反映したのか判断しづらいと思います。

レビュー指摘前後の変更内容が確認できて、かつ最終的なプルリクエストを1コミットにまとめることはできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

> おそらく、どのOSSでもそうだと思いますが

果たしてそうなのでしょうか、確かに複数コミットに分かれているとリベースを強要されたプロジェクトの話は聞いたことはありますが、懸念されている通りこの時点でコミットを纏めてしまうのは私は適切とは思いません。

GitHubのプルリクエストのマージは単純なツリーのマージ以外にもRebase，Squashの選択肢が用意されています。squashは1つのコミットとしてマージされるのでメンテナがこれを使っているのであればコントリビューターは意識する必要ありません。（それ以外においてもプルリク段階でsquashする必要があるのは稀な気はします。）

当然ながらこの辺りはプロジェクトの方針次第ですが……

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！コントリビューターがsquashせずに、レビュアー（メンテナー）がsquashして最終的に１コミットとするケースが多いんですかね？とすると、私のやり方であれば、２つ目の（rebase）コマンドが不要ということになりますか？

Comment: `squash`はあくまで`merge`を行う際のコマンドなので、これを実行できるのレビュアーやメンテナーのみです。 / `rebase`については使い方次第で`squash`と同じくコミットをまとめるものと思いがちですが、「コミットログをつなぎ直す」方がメインかなと。

Comment: @cubick さん、ありがとうございます。「プロジェクトの方針により異なるが、コントリビューターは随時修をレビュー指摘をコミットしていき、それをどうまとめるかはレビュアーに任せればよい」と考えておいて問題なさそうですかね？

Answer (score 0):

指摘事項が単純なタイプミスなど、変更点が軽微なものであれば `rebase` でまとめてしまうのもありかもしれませんが、そうでなければ「プルリクエストは必ず1コミットにまとめる」は必ずしも正しいとは言えません。

最終的にマージでどう取り込むかはオーナー次第ですが、コミットは "意味のある" 単位で分けるべきです。(今回の例なら、レビュー"前"と"後")

---

なお、GitHubのヘルプページには以下のような注意書きがありました。

https://help.github.com/ja/articles/about-pull-requests

> プルリクエストにコミットをプッシュする場合、フォースプッシュはしないでください。 フォースプッシュをすると、プルリクエストが壊れることがあります。

`rebase` を行うと新しいコミットハッシュが生成されるためでしょう。

Comment: force-pushedで表示されるようになったので、フォースプッシュ推奨というわけではないのでしょうが、禁止というほどでもないんじゃないかと。 https://github.blog/changelog/2018-11-15-force-push-timeline-event/

Comment: なるほど。１コミットにまとめていなくても、マージする側（メンテナ）は大変ではないんでしょうか?そちら側の立場で作業したことがないので、そのあたりが気になります。

Comment: @zakki プルリクエストが壊れなければ、フォースプッシュもアリってことですかね？